# calculating 3 similar sized groups in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, grouping

We have:

```
var range = [9,18,3,14,2,6,12,7,11,2,1,4]
var total = 89;
var group_size = total / 3;
```

As result I need 3 groups similar sized but     group1 and     group2 can never be bigger than     group_size.

The result for this example would be

```
var group1 = 27; // 9,18
var group2 = 25; // 3,14,2,6
var group3 = 37; // 12,7,11,2,1,4
```

How can I achieve this in Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I was glad to find this one as you seem to have deleted your old version of the question; and I've spent a fair bit of time on the algorithm...  I'm trying to write up my results, and will post them as a response here.

Comment: @user2843661: why the size restriction for the first two groups?  Your earlier versions of this question didn't mention this, I believe.

Comment: @Scott: thats correct. Also I saaw earlier today your answer and it looks great.

Comment: @user2843661: Well I hope this answer turns out helpful to you.  But even if not, it was a very interesting problem to investigate.  I am still curious as to whether that size restriction was something you forgot to mention the first time through or whether it was just something to make the code easier.  Because with that restriction, the code would actually be quite simple...

Comment: @Scott: I changed it in order to make it simpler.

Comment: @user2843661: Well, then mine answers the more complicated question.  If you really want to do the simpler question, I would suggest writing some simpler code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pop values with Javascript if you want this. Something like:

```
var range = [9,18,3,14,2,6,12,7,11,2,1,4]
var total = 89;
var group_size = total / 3;
var values = [0];
var groupnr = 0;
// Reverse the array, because pop will get the last element
range = range.reverse();

// While elements
while( range.length ) {
    // get the last element and remove from array
    var curvalue = range.pop();

    // To large, create a new element
    if( values[groupnr] + curvalue > group_size && groupnr < 2 ) {
         groupnr++;
         values[groupnr] = 0;
    }
    // Increase
    values[groupnr] += curvalue;
}
console.log(values);
```

Comment: thats almost what I am looking for. Only problem is that I get more than 3 groups with this approach. How to limit it to exactly 3 groups?

Comment: I have that, there is a limit if gruopnr < 2

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: This really answers a similar question (since removed by the author) which didn't include the restriction that the first two groups could not exceed the mean.  With that restriction, it's a much simpler problem, and one that probably wouldn't have caught my attention.  I'm leaving my answer here as the question it answers seems to be algorithmically interesting.

---

I have an answer using the **[Ramda functional programming library](https://github.com/CrossEye/ramda)**.  You can **[see it in action on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/X9GZf/)**.  (See below for an updated version of this that doesn't depend upon Ramda.) Ramda offers a number of convenient functions that make the code simpler.  None of them should be surprising if you're at all used to functional programming, although if you're used to tools like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [LoDash](http://lodash.com/) the parameter orders might seem backwards.  (Believe me, there is a good reason.)

```
var equalSplit = (function() {
    var square = function(x) {return x * x;};
    var variance = function(groups) {
        var sizes = map(sum, groups),
            mean = sum(sizes) / sizes.length;
        return sum(map(pipe(subtract(mean), square), sizes));
    };
    var firstGroupChoices = function(group, count) {
        if (group.length < 2 || count < 2) {return group;}
        var mean = sum(group) / count;
        var current = 0, next = group[0], idx = 0;
        do {
            current = next;
            next = next + group[++idx];
        } while (next < mean);
        if (next === mean) {
            return [group.slice(0, idx + 1)]
        } else {
            return [
                group.slice(0, idx),
                group.slice(0, idx + 1)
            ];
        }
    };
    var val = function(group, count, soFar) {
        if (count <= 0 || group.length == 0) {
            return {groups: soFar, variance: variance(soFar)};
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            return val([], 0, soFar.concat([group]));
        }
        var choices = firstGroupChoices(group, count);
        var values = map(function(choice){
            return val(group.slice(choice.length), count - 1, 
                       soFar.concat([choice]));
        }, choices);
        return minWith(function(a, b) {
            return a.variance - b.variance;
        }, values);
    };
    return function(group, count) {
        return val(group, count, []).groups;
    }
}());
```

Here is some sample output from the Fiddle:

```
==================================================
Input: [9,18,3,14,2,6,12,7,11,2,1,4]
Split into 3 groups
--------------------------------------------------
Groups: [[9,18,3],[14,2,6,12],[7,11,2,1,4]]
Totals: [30,34,25]
Variance: 40.66666666666667
==================================================

==================================================
Input: [9,18,3,2,6,12,11,2,4]
Split into 3 groups
--------------------------------------------------
Groups: [[9,18],[3,2,6,12],[11,2,4]]
Totals: [27,23,17]
Variance: 50.66666666666667
==================================================

==================================================
Input: [23,10,6,22,22,21,22,14,16,21,13,14,22,16,22,6,16,14,8,20,10,19,12,14,12]
Split into 5 groups
--------------------------------------------------
Groups: [[23,10,6,22,22],[21,22,14,16],[21,13,14,22],[16,22,6,16,14,8],
         [20,10,19,12,14,12]]
Totals: [83,73,70,82,87]
Variance: 206
==================================================
```

I am not at all convinced that this algorithm will give you an actual optimal solution.  I think there is some chance that a search might fall into a local minimum and not notice the global minimum in a nearby valley of the search space.  But I haven't tried very hard to either prove it or come up with a counterexample.  There is also a reasonable chance that it actually is correct.  I have no idea if there is some more efficient algorithm than this.  The problem feels vaguely like partitioning problems and knapsack problems, but I know I've never run across it before.  Many of those problems are NP Hard/NP Complete, so I wouldn't expect this to have a really efficient algorithm available.

This one works in a fairly simple recursive manner.  The internal `val` function accepts an array of numbers, the number of groups to create, and and accumulator (`soFar`) containing all the groups that have been created so far.  If `count` is zero, it returns a simple result based upon the accumulator.  If `count` is one, it recurs with an empty `group`, a `count` of zero, a an accumulator that now includes the original `group` as its last element.

For any other value of `count` it calculates the mean size of the remaining group, and then chooses the last initial partial sum of the group smaller than the mean and the first one larger than it (with a special case if there is one exactly equal to it), recurs to finds the value if those partial sequences are used as groups in the anser, and then returns the one with the smaller value.

Values are determined by calculated the variance in the total values of each subgroup formed.  The variance is the sum of the squares of the distance from the mean.

For instance, if you started with these values:

```
[8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1, 9]
```

And wanted to break them into three groups, you would have a mean of

```
(8 + 6 + 7 + 5 + 3 + 1 + 9 = 39)  / 3  => 13
```

If you broke them up like this:

```
[[8, 6], [7, 5, 3], [1, 9]]
```

you would have totals

```
[14, 15, 10]
```

and a variance of

```
(14 - 13)^2 + (15 - 13)^2 + (10 - 13)^2 => 14
```

But if you broke them like this:

```
[[8, 6], [7, 5], [3, 1, 9]]
```

your totals would be

```
[14, 12, 13]
```

and your variance would be

```
[14 - 13)^2 + (12 - 13)^2 + (13 - 13)^2 => 2
```

And since the latter split has the lower variance it is considered better.

### Example

```
equalSplit([9, 18, 3, 2, 6, 12, 11, 2, 4], 3 []) = minVal(
    equalSplit([18, 3, 2, 6, 12, 11, 2, 4], 2, [[9]]),
    equalSplit([3, 2, 6, 12, 11, 2, 4], 2, [[9, 18]])
);

equalSplit([18, 3, 2, 6, 12, 11, 2, 4], 2, [[9]]) =
    equalSplit([12, 11, 2, 4], 1, [[9], [18, 3, 2, 6]]);

equalSplit([3, 2, 6, 12, 11, 2, 4], 2, [9, 18]) = minVal(
    equalSplit([12, 11, 2, 4], 1, [[9, 18], [3, 2, 6]])
    equalSplit([11, 2, 4], 1,  [[9, 18], [3, 2, 6, 12]]
);

equalSplit([12, 11, 2, 4], 1, [[9], [18, 3, 2, 6]]) =
    equalSplit([], 0, [[9], [18, 3, 2, 6], [12, 11, 2, 4]])

equalSplit([12, 11, 2, 4], 1,  [[9, 18], [3, 2, 6]]) =
    equalSplit([], 0,  [[9, 18], [3, 2, 6], [12, 11, 2, 4]]) =

equalSplit([11, 2, 4], 1,  [[9, 18], [3, 2, 6, 12]]
    equalSplit([], 0,  [[9, 18], [3, 2, 6, 12], [11, 2, 4]]

equalSplit([], 0, [[9], [18, 3, 2, 6], [12, 11, 2, 4]]) =
    variance((9), (18 + 3 + 2 + 6), (12 + 11 + 2 + 4)) =
    variance(9, 29, 29) = 266.67

equalSplit([], 0,  [[9, 18], [3, 2, 6], [12, 11, 2, 4]]) =
    variance((9 + 18), (3 + 2 + 6), (12 + 11 + 2 + 4)) =
    variance(27, 11, 29)  = 194.67

equalSplit([], 0,  [[9, 18], [3, 2, 6, 12], [11, 2, 4]] =
    variance((9 + 18), (3 + 2 + 6 + 12), (11 + 2 + 4)) =
    variance(27, 23, 17)  = 50.67
```

There is almost certainly plenty that could be done to clean up this code.  But perhaps it's at least a start on your problem.  It's been a very interesting challenge.

---

### Update

I did create **[a version](http://jsfiddle.net/X9GZf/2/)** which does not depend upon Ramda.  The code is very similar.  (I guess I really didn't need Ramda, at least not for the final version.):

```
var equalSplit = (function() {
    var sum = function(list) {return list.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);};
    var square = function(x) {return x * x;};
    var variance = function(groups) {
        var sizes = groups.map(sum),
            mean = sum(sizes) / sizes.length;
        return sum(sizes.map(function(size) {
            return square(size - mean);
        }, sizes));
    };
    var firstGroupChoices = function(group, count) {
        if (group.length < 2 || count < 2) {return group;}
        var mean = sum(group) / count;
        var current = 0, next = group[0], idx = 0;
        do {
            current = next;
            next = next + group[++idx];
        } while (next < mean);
        if (next === mean) {
            return [group.slice(0, idx + 1)]
        } else {
            return [
                group.slice(0, idx),
                group.slice(0, idx + 1)
            ];
        }
    };
    var val = function(group, count, soFar) {
        if (count <= 0 || group.length == 0) {
            return {groups: soFar, variance: variance(soFar)};
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            return val([], 0, soFar.concat([group]));
        }
        var choices = firstGroupChoices(group, count);
        var values = choices.map(function(choice){
            return val(group.slice(choice.length), count - 1, 
                       soFar.concat([choice]));
        });
        return values.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.variance - b.variance;
        })[0];
    };
    return function(group, count) {
        return val(group, count, []).groups;
    }
}());
```

Of course, as now noted at the top, this answers a somewhat different question than is now being asked, but I think it's a more interesting question!  :-)

Comment: Groups: [[9,18],[3,2,6,12],[11,2,4]] -> you are missing a 1 on the last group here

Comment: I have no idea what your data example represents.  If it's simple, consistent data with only a few variations, you're much better off just hard-coding the results.  This is a tool to work with arbitrary input data.  You should be able to test it in the console or in any JS environment with the data you choose.  For example, if the missing `1` was in the penultimate position, you could do `equalSplit([9,18,3,2,6,12,11,2,1,4], 3) //=> [[9,18],[3,2,6,12],[11,2,1,4]]`