# split and group array javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
range = [a,3,b,2,c,1,d,2,e,3,f,3]
```

and need to group a,b,c,d,e,f into 3 same sized groups depending on their values.

Correct result would be:

```
group1 = [a]
group2 = [b,c]
group3 = [d,e,f]
```

Update: Pattern -> only group3 can be bigger then 1/3 of total groups. I have so far this:

```
var range = [3,2,1,2,3,3]
var total = 14;
var group_size = total / 3;
var values = [0];
var groupnr = 0;
range = range.reverse();

while( range.length ) {
var curvalue = range.pop();

if( values[groupnr] + curvalue > group_size && groupnr < 2 ) {
     groupnr++;
     values[groupnr] = 0;
}
values[groupnr] += curvalue;
}
log(values);
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: I don't see a pattern :(

Comment: updated my question with what i have done so far and the pattern

Comment: Can you explain with words, the procedure for grouping the elements of `range`? It is totally unclear how this is supposed to be done.

Comment: @Irfy: In words: I start on the left side and count the numbers together until max. 1/3 of the total group_size is reached. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user2843661 It is still unclear what needs to be done, e.g. what the letters and numbers represent. It appears though, that you are trying to solve a variant of the very well known [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), where in your case, you have three bins, objects `a` through `f` and their weights, and you need to distribute these objects according to their weight into these three bins, correct? Are you sure that there is no additional constraint on the maximum allowed "weight" per bin? Because your last bin has weight 8, much larger than `group_size`?

Comment: @lrfy: This poster has been trying variations of this in a number of questions, including some that have been removed.  I answered one, without the restriction that the first two groups cannot exceed the minimum in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220849/.  This is somewhat different, I believe from bin-packing problems or knapsack problems in that you really need only find the cut-points in the ordered sequence.  With the extra restriction that the initial ones cannot exceed the mean, this is not algorithmically interesting, I think, and should be relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's at least one possibility:

```
var equalSplit = (function() {
    var sum = function(list) {return list.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);};
    var evens = function(list) {
        return list.filter(function(item, index) {return !(index % 2);})
    };
    var odds = function(list) {
        return list.filter(function(item, index) {return !!(index % 2);})
    };
    var split = function(values, count) {
        var mean = sum(values) / values.length;
        var groups = [], index = 0, total, groupStart;
        for (var i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
            total = 0; groupStart = index;
            while (index < values.length && total < mean) {
                total += values[index++];
            }
            groups.push(values.slice(groupStart, index));
        }
        groups.push(values.slice(index));
        return groups;
    };
    var reconstituteRanges = function(ranges, splits) {
        var groups = {}, ctr = 0, diff;
        for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
            diff = splits[i].length
            groups["group" + (i + 1)] = 
                    (evens(ranges.slice(ctr, ctr+=(2 * diff))));
        }
        return groups;
    };
    return function(ranges, count) {
        var values = odds(ranges);
        var splits = split(values, count);
        return reconstituteRanges(ranges, splits);
    }
}());

var ranges = ['a',3,'b',2,'c',1,'d',2,'e',3,'f',3];
console.log(equalSplit(ranges, 3));
//=> {"group1":["a"],"group2":["b","c"],"group3":["d","e","f"]}
```

You can see it in action on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/jQa4V/)**.

This problem is much simpler than **[an earlier version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226073/1243641)**, although the code is not that much shorter.

But do you really want to let the last group carry all the weight like this?  You originally posted wanting them to be closer to equal.  In this case, your weighted totals are [3, 3, 8] for a fairly high variance of 16.67, where [['a'],['b','c','d'],['e','f']] would balance better at [3, 5, 6] for a variance of only 4.67.  Is this really your requirement, or was this just a way to write simpler code?  (Although this code is not too much shorter than my answer to the previous one, it is substantially simpler.)

Comment: Thank you Scott! This is e x a c t l y what I was looking for. I will now double check with your earlier version and see what fits the best my needs. I hope somebody might find my problem and your answer helpful. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var range = ['a',3,'b',2,'c',1,'d',2,'e',3,'f',3];
var obj = {};

range.map(function(el, i) {
    if (i%2) {
        var k = 'group'+el;
        obj[k] = obj[k] || [];
        obj[k].push(range[i-1]);
    }
});
```

gives you

```
{
    "group1" : ["c"]
    "group2" : ["b","d"],
    "group3" : ["a","e","f"],
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzcN2/)

That's about the only thing that would make sense ?